# Why am I receiving a floating point exception when I run the following code?

Tags: c

Basically it's a code to input the scores and calculating if the student has passed or not, based upon a criterion. In VScode, after taking the input values, the program just terminates without either a return value of 0 or an error. In an online C compiler, Float point exception prints out in the terminal. What's going on?

```
int main(){
    int enteries; 
    scanf("%d", &enteries); 

    int pass, fail, spass, sfail, avg = 0;
    

    while ( enteries != 0){
        int score;
        printf("Print score"); 
        scanf("%d", &score); 
        if (score<60){
            fail = fail + 1; 
            sfail = score + sfail;
            enteries -= 1;
        }
        else if(score >= 60 && score <=100){
            pass = pass + 1; 
            spass = spass + score;
            enteries -= 1; 
        }
         
    } 

    int sum = spass + sfail; 
    avg = sum / enteries; 
    printf("%d" , avg);  

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: ... because you are very certainly dividing by zero!

Comment: Use your debugger to follow the values in the variables, if you cannot deduce it from your own code: Think about the value of `enteries` during the loop and when it comes to the division.

Comment: Most of the variables you manipulate have undefined values.

Comment: Where are your `#include`s ? They really matter.

Comment: Read this: [ask]. Then [edit] the question and show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Note that the line `int pass, fail, spass, sfail, avg = 0;` initializes only `avg` — all the other variables are uninitialized.  You need `int pass = 0; int fail = 0; int spass = 0; int sfail = 0; int avg = 0;` — using separate declarations for each variable, though you could replace the sequence `; int` with a comma too.  Also, for `for (int i = 0; i < enteries; i++)` to control the loop, leaving `enteries` unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to debug the code. I am a beginner so excuse my stupidities...

Answer (score 2):

After the `while ( enteries != 0)` while-loop, `enteries` will be zero.

Then

```
avg = sum / enteries;
```

divides by zero, causing a divide-by-zero exception.

Comment: That's _one_ problem in the OP's code.